# Interface Builder -- Really strange frame Origins on UIView in a NIB

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I am building a custom component, and I've decided to build it with a custom `UIView` in a NIB.   There are several other `UIView`'s positioned in this same nib document, but all are at the root level.

**As you can see, all of these elements have od X/Y that (to me) are not intuitive at all.**

The Container `UIView`: (why does X=122 and Y=42)
[image]

The first subcontainer `UIView` is the top half (first 4 fields)
**Why does X=122 and Y=22? Obviously it's positioned at the top-left of its parent**
[image]

The second subcontainer `UIView` is the top half (second 4 fields)
**Why does X=122 and Y=62? I would expect it to be positioned at X=0 and Y=43?**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the red cross on the middle of the first Inspector view? Right above the "Origin" label. Click on the upper-left corner and the anchor will move to there, and your coordinate system will be back to normal.

Comment: You're very welcome, having already made the mistake myself ;)